# Why is my pc saying I have only 1 4g stick of ram in the 4th slot when I have 8g of ram 1 stick in the second and one in the 4th

Tags: memory, hardware-detection

I built my PC on Monday this week and I just noticed last night that in my task manager it is saying that I only have 1 stick of ram installed into the 4th slot even though I have two sticks one in the 2nd and one in the 4th. I opened up my pc and took out the ram in the second slot and pushed it back in but when booted up my pc it still wasn't being detected.[Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9jw1.jpg)

Comment: For using 3.2GHz RAM you need to activate XMP profile in BIOS for RAM "overclocking", otherwise only the standardized 2.6GHz is used. I recommend to use CPU-Z instead of taskmager, it shows way more details.

Comment: What if you change to slots 1 & 3

Comment: @Robert - That doesn’t explain the reason 8 GB isn’t detected

Answer (score 0):

Does your motherboard accommodate ram above 2666Mhz? I have seen this before. sounds like you have two sticks of Ram for a total of 8Gb, but they might be mismatched vendors or speeds: are they the same brand, and configuration? are both pieces 2x4gb 3200Mhz from Kingston or Corsair, or another vendor?

Comment: They are both this RAM t.ly/lGJ7

Comment: my motherboard only supports 2666mhz now that I have looked it up but the main issue is that I cannot utilize my snd slot stick of ram.

Comment: @Saint - Have you confirmed it’s fully installed because it’s not even detected